# How to pass sensitive data to my python application

Tags: python, security, passwords, server-side, server-side-attacks

I want to pass a critically sensitive key to my python application. Say an attacker gets root access to the server. I don't want him to discover the key by any means. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you have tried after reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You cannot achieve this.